# Can anyone tell me why its skipping the if statement even when the time is 3:37:00?

Tags: python

```
class Define_time:
def __init__(self):
    pass

d = Define_time()
d.real_time = time.strftime('%l:%M:%S')

def capture_time():
    d.real_time = time.strftime('%l:%M:%S')
    return d.real_time

while True:
    capture_time()
    if d.real_time == '3:37:00':
        time.sleep(1)
        s.login(smtpUser, smtpPass)
        s.sendmail(fromAdd, toAdd, header + '\n' + body)
        print('Email Sent')
        time.sleep(5)
    else:
        print(d.real_time)
```

Comment: check the length of the string

Comment: also try `if '3:37:00' == '3:37:00':`

Comment: So, the else-part prints "3:37:00" at that time each day, right?

Comment: The script is incomplete and incorrectly formatted.

Comment: The length of string seemed to be the problem. I changed it to ' 3:37:00': instead of '3:37:00':  Thanks!

Comment: more elegant solution is `if d.real_time.strip() == '3:37:00':`

Comment: Post this kind of question on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions) instead of here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

%l if not part of standard formatting for python but assuming you are on Linux it's:

```
%l     The hour (12-hour clock) as a decimal number (range 1 to 12);
              single digits are preceded by a blank.  (See also %I.)
              (Calculated from tm_hour.)  (TZ)
```

**Note:** **"single digits are preceded by a blank".**

So your string is " 3:37:00".

I suggest using %H:%M:%S instead.

Answer (score 1):

Looking for this code to solve the problem:

```
def capture_time():
    d.real_time = time.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
    return d.real_time

while True:
    capture_time()
    if d.real_time == '15:37:00':`
```